# Mystery Permission Sets assigned to Guest Users?

Tags: soql, salesforce-id, permission-sets

To prepare for the upcoming Release Update "Remove Guest User Assignments from Permission Sets Associated with Permission Set Licenses with Restricted Object Permissions", I ran a SOQL query in the Developer Console (based on https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000319607&type=1 ):

```
SELECT Id, PermissionSetId, PermissionSet.Name, PermissionSet.ProfileId, AssigneeId, Assignee.Name FROM PermissionSetAssignment WHERE Assignee.Name LIKE '%Guest%'
```

This query found a few Permission Sets. All of the columns except Assignee.Name displayed SFID strings *(furthermore, PermissionSet Name & Profile changed into* [object Object] *when I clicked on them)*. The Permission Set IDs do not correspond to any items in the Permission Sets list. When I try to access the SFIDs directly in the URL bar, it says Insufficient Privileges (I'm System Admin).

What are they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every Profile has an associated Permission Set where IsProfileOwned = true. This allows developers to query all of a user's permissions in one place. These entries shouldn't be affected by this update.